# What tracking solutions are available for server side code?

Tags: python, google-analytics, tracking, google-analytics-api

I'm working on a tracking proxy (for want of a better term) written in Python. It's a simple http (wsgi) application that will run on one (maybe more) server and accepts event data from a desktop client.  This service would then forward the tracking data on to some actual tracking platform (DeskMetrics, MixPanel, Google Analytics) so that we don't have to deal with the slicing and dicing of data.

The reason for this implementation is that it's much easier and faster to make changes to a server process that we control rather than having to ensure every client in the wild gets updated if the tracking backend changes in some way.

I've been looking up info on the various options and I was hoping somebody here would have some good advice from their own experiences.  Ideally we'd be able to use Google Analytics as it's free for any amount of usage but paid options are fine.

My only real requirement is either a good Python library or a well documented api that I can write a wrapper for (this seems somewhat lacking in GA when it comes to triggering events through any method other than their js or other provided libs).

N.B. We're not really tracking server code so something like NewRelic isn't appropriate, we're just decoupling a desktop application from the specifics of the tracking backend.

Comment: "Every client in the wild"? Are you referring to a mobile application? you should explain a little bit more about your application so we could understand the nature of the data you're talking about and the reasoning behind this.

Comment: @EduardoCereto End of the very first sentence "desktop client" (and last sentence for that matter "desktop application"). It's standard usage tracking to gain some insight into what users are doing the most so that work can be focused on the most used features to make them really kick ass. What buttons are people clicking in the application, how much time are they spending within various flows, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried anything below?

The Google Data APIs Python Client Library has source specific to analytics

- http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/
- http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/#hg%2Fsamples%2Fanalytics
- https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/python_client_lib

You might be able to borrow from these sources as well;
Google has something they are working on for mobile and source is available in PHP, JSP, ASP.net and Perl: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/mobileWebsites

I also came accross this in PHP http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/

As for others:

- KissMetrics: http://support.kissmetrics.com/apis/python
- MixPanel: https://mixpanel.com/docs/integration-libraries/python
- DeskMetrics: don't seem to have python, http://docs.deskmetrics.com/index.html

Sorry I cannot provide information based off extensive experience with anything python related other then providing a few  of these resources. I would be interested to see what you come up with.

Answer (score 12):

We ran into this same problem a bunch of times, we ended up building a suite of server-side analytics libraries to make this easier.

Segment.io has libraries for [Python](https://segment.io/libraries/python), [Ruby](https://segment.io/libraries/ruby), [Java](https://segment.io/libraries/java), [Node](https://segment.io/libraries/node), [.NET](https://segment.io/libraries/.net) and [PHP](https://segment.io/libraries/php) that abstract the APIs for Mixpanel, KISSmetrics, Google Analytics and a bunch of other analytics services.

You could integrate the Python library once, and then send your data wherever you want. The data is proxied through Segment.io's hosted service. Hopefully this cleans up the mess of integrating a bunch of libraries, each with slightly different APIs. (The service is free for the first million events.)

Comment: Dude, thank you so much. I found Segment.io randomly the other day and forgot to bookmark it. I've been trying to find it for the past few hours because my google-foo was failing me pretty hard on "visitor tracking" queries.